# Install vscode extension through vsix file without CLI command

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to install vscode extension vsix file by double clicking it without using CLI command as mentioned [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#packaging-extensions) - `code --install-extension my-extension-0.0.1.vsix`

The extension is not yet published and in development mode that we'd like to share for preview.

But I'm getting the following error:-

```
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - -------------------------------------------
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - 16.8.3036
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - -------------------------------------------
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - Command line parameters:
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\jmadhu\Desktop\dev\CloudNativeTest\vscode-azureloadtest\vscode-azureloadtest-0.1.0.vsix
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - -------------------------------------------
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
03-03-2021 13:06:46 - -------------------------------------------
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - Initializing Install...
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - Extension Details...
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   Identifier         : vscode-azureloadtest
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   Name               : Azure Load Test
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   Author             : ms-azureloadtest
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   Version            : 0.1.0
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   Description        : Manage your Azure Cloud Native Load Tests and Resources
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   Locale             : en-US
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   MoreInfoURL        : 
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - 
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   SignatureState     : Unsigned
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   Supported Products : 
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -           Version : 
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - 
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   References         : 
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - Signature Details...
03-03-2021 13:06:47 -   Extension is not signed.
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - 
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - Searching for applicable products...
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - Found installed product - Global Location
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2019
03-03-2021 13:06:47 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: One or more extensions are for Visual Studio Code. Try installing them in Visual Studio Code.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Ques: Can we install vsix file (unpublished extension) without using CLI command? If yes, what are the possible ways?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only install via menu items,

> "You can manually install a VS Code extension packaged in a .vsix
> file. Using the Install from VSIX command in the Extensions view
> command drop-down, or the Extensions: Install from VSIX command in the
> Command Palette, point to the .vsix file."

from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_install-from-a-vsix

You cannot double click such files to install in Windows Explorer, because Visual Studio registers another tool (aka Microsoft VSIX Installer) there, which won't work for VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with VSCode 1.77 (March 2023), installing VSIX [from CLI](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line) is supported (see "[Working with extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions)").

This is from [issue 175673](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175673) and [PR 175675](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/175675), released to [VSCode insider today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

The `--install-extension` option now supports `ExtensionId` or VSIX.

Comment: @JackPunt OK. I must have been confused with all the `else if (this.args['install-extension'] || this.args['install-builtin-extension']) {` I saw in the [PR code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/175675/files).

Comment: you're right. i tried to [immediately] delete my comment, but the delete failed . (it fails from my compiled vscode-oss scripts/code.sh command-line...)

Comment: @JackPunt No problem. I appreciate the confirmation.